# Get the time difference based on the timezone and current servertime

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following are relevant columns in my table, each line represents a column below.

```
COLUMN username character varying(100);
COLUMN started_using_at timestamp with time zone;
COLUMN timezone text;
```

The timezone column contains data like below

```
America/New_York
America/Chicago
etc....
```

How can I create a query that when passing the `username` in the where clause, I can get the time difference between `started_using_at` and the current time on the server, respective to the `timezone`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tolerate two separate queries, you can first look up the user's timezone, then do this:

```
SET timezone='America/New_York';
SELECT NOW() - started_using_at FROM t WHERE username = 'fred';
```

Unfortunately this is a syntax error:

```
SET timezone=(SELECT timezone FROM t WHERE username = 'fred');
```

**BUT**: Remember that both `NOW()` and `started_using_at` are both *instants*. Internally they are just stored as seconds since the epoch. The timezone only matters when you go to stringify them or decide in which day they belong. So really this should give you the same results regardless of the user's timezone:

```
SELECT NOW() - started_using_at FROM t WHERE username = 'fred';
```

You don't even need to worry about timezones here!

Comment: You are right I don't even need to worry about timezones.